# How do I compare an integer with a message in a discord channel read by a bot?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a really simple bot that I need in a server. It's job is really simple. 
To better understand what I need: I have a channel where people must guess a certain number between 1 and 50000. If they guess It they win and the bot announces that. 
What I need is that the bot checks every message and if It's not a number between 1 and 50000 It deletes the message.

Currently this is all I have. I tried numerous things like trying to convert the "message" into an integer, but It won't let me.

```
@client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if(message.channel.id == "492772765737156628"):
            if message.content > 50000:
                await client.delete_message(message)
```

I'm really new to coding especially in python and know only some of the basics. I thank every answer and help I get :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't let me convert the message into an integer"? Does it return something unexpected, throw an error or otherwise?

Comment: @DWuest I tried putting _message = int(message)_ right after async def on_message(message). It threw me an error __TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Message'__

Comment: You can't call int on message itself since it is an instance of the class 'Message'. Try `val = int(message.content)` instead.

Comment: However, before you do that, check first if you can even convert it into an integer, since the program would throw an error if the message was simply something like `'abc'`.

Comment: After trying to put `val = int(message.content)` in instead it threw me _TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'_ So I suppose I did something wrong or that didn't convert it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `message.content` (a string) as an integer, not `message` (a `Message` object that contains lots of other data).

There are 3 possibilities for the value of `message.content`:

1. Non-integer text
2. Integer text > 50000
3. Integer text <= 50000

you can test for all of these

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if(message.channel.id == "492772765737156628"):
        try:
            content = int(message.content)
            if content > 50000:
                await client.delete_message(message)
        except ValueError:
            await client.delete_message(message)  # not an integer
```